# How to read a string from a below line?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this:

```
//VIOLATION_IGNORED
T_CH  *i_pCH2string;
```

I would like to read //VIOLATION_IGNORED from the second line. How could I process using a regex?

I am writing it using an [Understand API](http://www.scitools.com/plugins/). Understand is a static analysis tool using it own API through perl to write it scripts. I just need a regular expression to read the first line, from the second one.

Comment: the first line is //VIOLATION_IGNORED and the second one is 
T_CH *i_pCH2string;

Comment: what do you mean? what code do you have?

Comment: I have a C code and i am writing a perl script to parse the code through a static analysis tool. Then, from the second line, i would like to be able to read the first one, and then tell to my tool to ignore this violation

Comment: What perl script do you have?

Comment: I am writing it using an Understand API. Understand is a static analysis tool using it own API through perl to write it scripts.,,I just need a regular expression to read the first line, from the second one...Thank you

Comment: What would you like to capture? Instead of expressing it in lines, perhaps you can say something like "I'd like to capture the comment before any line that has a T_CH declaration"

Comment: Rephrasing the question probably makes the problem both easier to understand and to implement.Something like "if the current line is `//VIOLATION_IGNORED`, how do I avoid issuing a warning for any violation on the immediately following line"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't read the preceding line... you just remember what was on it.
Pseudocode:

```
while(<>) {
   if ((/\/\/VIOLATION_IGNORED/) {$ignore=1;next;} # ignore violation on next line
   if (violation($_)) {                            # yo' bad?
       if($ignore) {ignore=0; next;}               # never mind
    } else {
       blow_up($_);                                # take this!
    }
   ignore=0;                                       # reset flag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you're after?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @file = ('//VIOLATION_IGNORED', 'T_CH  *i_pCH2string');

my $current_line = "";

foreach (@file){
    my $previous_line = $current_line;
    $current_line = $_;
        if ($current_line =~ /T_CH.*?/ ){
            print "$previous_line\n"
            # Do something else? ...
        }
}
```

Output:

```
//VIOLATION_IGNORED
```

Or, if you simply want to ignore lines containing //VIOLATION_IGNORED:

```
foreach (@array1){
    next if $_ =~ /\/\/VIOLATION_IGNORED/;
    print "$_\n";
    # Do something else? ...
}
```

Output:

```
T_CH  *i_pCH2string
```

Comment: Thanx...What if the second line could be anything ?

Comment: Just use: `unless ($_ =~ /\/\/VIOLATION_IGNORED/ ){
 ... }
`